# Find expectation $E(X)$ in a probability problem

Tags: probability

> At work they play secret friend (secret santa gift exchange). Everyone sits in a circle randomly and each
> one gives a gift to the one on the right or the one on the left, without knowing who is on the right and
> who to the left (is to avoid preferences). For each, the choice of giving it to the
> the right or the left is random with probability $0.5$ of giving it to the right and $0.5$
> to give it to the one on the left.  Find the expectation of the number of participants that end without a gift, if in total there are $200$ people.

**Idea:** Is not hard to imagine cases where people end wihout gift, for example if circle starts in $A$ and ends in $B$, then anyone in one side gives a gift to the next, but the last participant $B$ do not gives a gift to $A$ who is the next, instead he gives the gift to the the previous person, so $A$ ends without gift. Diagram: A---->O----->O---->O----><B.
How to extend this idea to find the answer?

Comment: This is a good candidate for Linearity of Expectation.  Just work out the probability that a particular individual winds up empty handed.

Comment: @lulu Is it means that if $p$ is the probability of winds up empty handed, then $np$ is the expectation? where $n=200$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable that equals $1$ if the $i_{th}$ person doesn't receive a gift, and $0$ otherwise.

Then $\Bbb {P}(X_i)$

$= \Bbb P$[not receive gift from both $(i-1) \;and\; (i+1)$ person]

$ = \frac12\cdot\frac12 = \frac14$

Now the expectation of an indicator variable is just the probability of the event it indicates,

thus $\Bbb E[X_i] = \Bbb P(X_i) = \frac14$

and by linearity of expectation, which applies even if the variables are not independent,

$\Bbb E[X] = \Bbb E[X_1] + \Bbb E[X_2] + ... + \Bbb E[X_{200}] = 200\cdot\frac14 = 50$